# Update MySQL table from HTML table

Tags: html, mysql, pdo

So, I have this MySQL table with a bunch of users, which I insert using a form. On another page, I get the entire table in to a HTML table. Now, I'd like to have a final column in the HTML table with a link which will change a boolean in that MySQL table row. I've got everything down, except the "how to place the link in the table".

Here's my code (sorry about the mess):

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
                function __construct($it) {
                    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
                }

                function current() {
                    return "<td style='width:150px;border:0px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
                }

                function beginChildren() {
                    echo "<tr>";
                }

                function endChildren() {
                    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
                }
            }
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ureg', $dbuser, $dbpass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $dbh->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, fname, lname, company, phone, details, inside, timein, timeout, assigned_card, edit FROM visitors");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
                echo $v;
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

If you have any questions regarding my problem, feel free to comment.

EDIT: Sample output as it is right now. (Localized to English to help)

```
<tbody>
<tr><th>ID</th>
<th>First name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Details</th>
<th>Inside</th>
<th>Time in</th>
<th>Time out</th>
<th>Assigned ID-card</th>
<th>Stamp out</th></tr>
<tr><td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">9</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">User</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">Userson</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">AT&amp;T</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">12345678</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;"></td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">1</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">2015-05-21 15:29:34</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;">4421</td>
<td style="width:150px;border:0px solid black;"></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I've marked an image with the field I want the link to appear on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBZH8.jpg

Comment: _I've got everything down, except the "how to place the link in the table"_ - so is it that you just need to create the `<a>` tag to make a link in the markup, or that you also need to write all the backend code to make it update the boolean? As posted, your code includes nothing to modify values in the database, and that makes this question very broad.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski When I say everything down, I mean I can manage to update the boolean if I could place down individual links (index.php?id=2) for each row. Like, I know where to go from there. My issue is making individual links for each row. My English isn't the best, I'm sorry! :)

Comment: Ok so mainly your concern is how to get an `id=` value from the current iteration into the string returned by `current()`?  Can you  post a sample of the output HTML it produces now?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski OP updated with some more information.